# How can a view be placed on top of the navigation bar of a UINaviagationController subclass?

Tags: swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

The root view controller `HomeTableViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. How can a subView take over the whole screen and be placed on top of the navigation bar of the `CustomNavigation: UINavigationController` class?

This is the code I am using:

```
       if var player = self.moviePlayer {
            player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
            player.controlStyle = .None
            // self.view.addSubview(player.view)
            self.navigationController.view.addSubview(player.view)
        }
```

I see the error:

> 'UINavigationController?' does not have a member named 'view'

This is my Main.storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So easy...

```
navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html